# Объясните поведение QSslSocket, приведенного к типу умного указателя с помощью std::make_shared

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, qt5, smart-pointer

На стороне клиента при возникновении нового подключения пытаюсь создать умный указатель сокет, чтобы добавить его в QMap и дальше работать с ними.

```
QSslSocket *client = dynamic_cast<QSslSocket*>(nextPendingConnection());
Q_ASSERT(client);
client->setProperty("type", QString("CLIENT"));
std::shared_ptr<QSslSocket> sock =  std::make_shared<QSslSocket>(client);
...
```

Но теперь **sock->property("type").toString()** возвращает пустую строку, и также мы не можем ничего записать в сокет, так как он закрыт.

Если работать с client, то все нормально, в том числе в контексте других слотов.

Пробовал с QSharedPointer, та же картина

```
QSharedPointer<QSslSocket> sck = QSharedPointer<QSslSocket>::create(client);
```

Объясните такое поведение.
Debian, gcc 4.7.2

**UPD** Хм, а если передать в QMap просто SharedPointer(client), то работает...

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь не использовать умные указатели с разделяемым владением (`shared_ptr` / `QSharedPointer`) с объектами-наследниками `QObject`, поскольку у последних не предусмотрено копирование, да и контроль за длительностью "жизни" производится, как правило, посредством передачи указателя на родителя его дочерним объектам (не путать с наследованием). По той же причине, не рекомендуется использовать и единолично-владеющие указатели (`unique_ptr` / `QScopedPointer`), т.к. потребуется в обязательном порядке объявить дочернему `QObject`, что он не имеет родителя (`parent`).

В Вашей ситуации с `QSslSocket` - это как раз такой случай. Объекту уже назначен родитель (скорее всего `QTcpServer`), и как только тот перейдёт к процессу ликвидации, это автоматом уничтожит и экземпляр `QSslSocket`, который Вы пытаетесь упаковать в умный указатель. Что произойдёт дальше, думаю, вполне очевидно. Поэтому, если всё же есть основание на то, чтобы "упрятать" наследника `QObject` в умный указатель, не забудьте предварительно выполнить следующее:

```
QSslSocket *client = qobject_cast<QSslSocket*>(nextPendingConnection());
client->setParent(nullptr);
```

Несмотря на некоторую несогласованность с STL по обозначенной теме, в Qt всё же есть умные указатели, предназначенные для работы с наследниками `QObject`. Это `QPointer`. В чём-то похожие ему аналоги - это `std::weak_ptr` и конечно `QWeakPointer`. Данный тип указателей не владеет объектами в полной мере, но позволяет определять факт их "жизни" или "смерти". И в отличие от аналогичных указателей, в `QPointer` можно вставлять объект (наследника `QObject`) в любое время, а не только в момент создания.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Обясните на примере работы с сокетами в Qt: я в переопределенном методе incomingConnection(qintptr handle), создаю новый сокет new QSslSocket, присваиваю ему handle и кидаю его дальше в addPendingConnection(sock). Как в таком случае организовать безопасную очистку памяти при, допустим, разрыве соединения? Если передать parent QTcpServer, то очистка будет только по завершении сервера, как я понял. Возможно это без new/delete?